# Getting direction from single universal laser

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, 2dlaserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have 360 degrees laser coverage around a robot with the data published into a single topic. But because of that I can not tell what laser data reflects right, left, front or back or the robot.

Just wondering if there is a technic for detecting direction from a single universal laser reading ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383882/getting-direction-from-single-universal-laser/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2021-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

if the message is a standard `sensor_msgs/LaserScan`, there are fields describing the angular coverage of the scan. The ray lengths in the `ranges[]` array should be ordered sequentially from `angle_min` up to almost `angle_max`, sweeping counter-clockwise if you look down from above.

The answer to your question is that, for the standard LaserScan message, angle 0.0 is "forward" in the sensor's own transform frame.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2021-08-05**:
Thank you Mike.
I will look into that.